# A simple project

Tags: vs-web-site-project

I want to build a website that is a simple password generator and that has a nice design.
passwordbird is a simple password generator and http://www.atebits.com/ has a design that I really like. What languages should I use for this project? My main goal is to gain experience in building websites; I don't expect for it to be perfect. I just want to learn something new and apply it to an idea that I have.

Comment: Not trying to crush your hopes, dreams, aspirations - **but**, if you're going to get any sort of a useful, meaningful answer out of a totally open-ended question like this (_"What language should I use to build a website?"_), you've got to provide _way_ more detail. What languages do you already know? What languages would you like to know? What do you want your website to do? For a static website, you don't _need_ anything beyond straight-up HTML, CSS, and JavaScript - that's all that any other language will ultimately produce anyway.

Comment: I know C and java and I want to build a dynamic website that is a password generator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML, CSS and JS. Here's an example JS script on password generation: http://javascript.internet.com/passwords/password-generator.html

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Good training would be a basic HTML&CSS site, and a php script to generate a password.

I imagine you would be able to specify things like length and composition of the password right? Throw all that in a form and send it via Ajax to the php script, get the generated password and display it. For the Javascript(Ajax) part, I'd use [JQuery](http://jquery.com)

Comment: I don't think you read the question fully.